# Asset compression in Rails 4.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am having trouble forcing the assets to compress for my app.

I have included the following lines in production.rb:

```
config.assets.compress = true
config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
config.assets.css_compressor = :yui
```

The gem file includes the following gems:

```
gem 'execjs' #Run JS code from Ruby
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3' #SASS adapter
gem 'yui-compressor' #CSS compression
gem 'uglifier', '~> 2.5.0' #compacts JS files
```

Is there anything else I need to add?

Here's the rest of the production.rb file

```
# Code is not reloaded between requests.
config.cache_classes = true

# Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
# your application in memory, allowing both thread web servers
# and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
# Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
config.eager_load = true

# Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
config.consider_all_requests_local = false
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

# Enable Rack::Cache to put a simple HTTP cache in front of your application
# Add `rack-cache` to your Gemfile before enabling this.
# For large-scale production use, consider using a caching reverse proxy like nginx, varnish or squid.
# config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = true

# Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this).
config.serve_static_assets = false

# Compress JavaScripts and CSS
config.assets.compress = true

# Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
config.assets.css_compressor = :yui

# Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
config.assets.compile = true

# Generate digests for assets URLs.
config.assets.digest = true

# Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets.
config.assets.version = '1.0'

# Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
# config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile" # for apache
# config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for nginx

# Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
config.force_ssl = true

# Set to :debug to see everything in the log.
config.log_level = :info

# Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
# config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

# Use a different logger for distributed setups.
# config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

# Use a different cache store in production.
# config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

# Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
# config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://fathomless-ocean-4567.herokuapp.com"

# Precompile additional assets.
# application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS in app/assets folder are already added.
config.assets.precompile = ['*.js', '*.css', '*.css.erb']

# Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
# Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
# config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

# Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
# the I18n.default_locale when a translation can not be found).
config.i18n.fallbacks = true

# Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

# Disable automatic flushing of the log to improve performance.
# config.autoflush_log = false

# Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new
```

And here's the application.rb file:

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)
require "active_record/railtie"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "sprockets/railtie"
require 'csv'

Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env)

config.assets.precompile += %w(*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif)
config.active_record.schema_format = :sql
```

Comment: So what is happening? (and how does it differ from what you expected)

Comment: I know the compression is not working because when I comment out the config.assets.js_compressor lines, the JS is approximately 900kb. When the config.assets.js_compressor lines are present, the size is still about 900kb with comments and spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Now you just need to put your assets in the correct path (`./app/assets`) and run `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile`. Are you getting any error?

Comment: Nope, I'm not getting any errors while running assets:precompile. The assets are in app/assets. I know the compression is not working because when I comment out the config.assets.js_compressor lines, the JS is approximately 900kb. When the config.assets.js_compressor lines are present, the size is still about 900kb with comments and spaces.

Comment: please, try to clean your browser cache and check if your assets are present and compressed in /public/assets

Comment: Thanks! For some reason, it works after I delete the existing precompiled assets from /public/app